# My class Controler doesnt see methods from my Service class

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

Hi everyone i was started to make from scratch my Spring Boot Application. I want to make Booking Application for my portfolio. I am a begginner in coding,past one year I have learning Java. I'm struggling whole day and I don't know where I have problem when I want to call `getUser` method in my Controller Class? Simply controller class doesn't see 
method's is my Service Class.

Class's are in four different packages

```
 com.booking.controller
 com.booking.model
 com.booking.repository
 com.service
```

Here I have problem, simply it can't see service class.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/user")
public class UserController{
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@GetMapping(path = "/add")
public @ResponseBody String addNewUser(@RequestParam String name, 
@RequestParam String username,
        @RequestParam String email, @RequestParam String password) {

    User n = new User();
    n.setName(name);
    n.setUsername(username);
    n.setEmail(email);
    n.setPassword(password);
    userRepository.save(n);
    return "Saved";
}

@GetMapping(path = "/all")
public @ResponseBody Iterable<User> getAllUsers() {
    return userRepository.findAll();
}

@RequestMapping("/{Id}")
public User getUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return userRepository.getUser(id);
/*Here you can see problem*/
}

}
```

**My User Class**

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column
private String name;

@Column
private String username;

@Column
private String email;

@Column
private String password;

public User() {

}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

}
```

**My Repository Class--

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    public List<User> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

**My Service Class**

```
@Service
public class UserService {
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

public List<User> getAllUsers(String username) {
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    userRepository.findByUsername(username).forEach(users::add);
    return users;
}

public User getUser(Long id) {
    return userRepository.findOne(id);
}

public void addUser(User user) {
    userRepository.save(user);
}

public void updateUser(Long id, User user) {
    userRepository.save(user);
}

public void deleteUser(Long id) {
    userRepository.delete(id);
}

}
```

Comment: You are calling `getUser()` on `UserRepository`, not on `UserService` in your controller. You also don't even use `UserService` in your controller.

Comment: I didn't saw,thank you so much.I have fixed.